# Botón Aceptar Cookies (Selenium,Python)

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, xpath, popup

Buenos días mi nombre es Santiago y estoy intentando hacer scraping con python y selenium en la web Investing.

Bien, mi problema consiste en que cuando accedo a la url de Investing salta una ventana emergente pidiendo que acepte las cookies. Hasta ahí no hay problema, el problema viene cuando busco el XPath del botón para aceptar las cookies pero python me dice que selenium no ha encontrado esa dirección Xpath y por tanto que no puede hacer click en algo que para el no existe.

Este es el código

```
from selenium import webdriver

web_null = 'https://www.investing.com/indices/germany-30-components'
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(web_null)
time.sleep(3)

boton=browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[8]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/a[1]').click()
```

Os muestro también el popup que aparece y que no puedo hacer click:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: deseas clickear en "Got it" o quieres entrar en 'avanzadas' (donde supongo debe tener la opción de denegar ?

Comment: En principio me sirve dando en Got it

Comment: He intentado simular la navegación, pero no tengo éxito para que se dispare ese modal de cookies. Pero puedes hacer el intento de `browser.find_element_by_link_text('Got it').click()` ?. Si no es posible puedes hacer `print(browser.page_source)` y busca la palabra "Got it", para ver dentro de que elemento y clase se encuentra el boton

Comment: Con la orden de browser.find_element_by_link_text('Got it').click() me devuelve un error como con el XPATH selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: Got it                                Es decir que busca en el código de la página y no encuentra ese texto. Voy a probar con la otra opción que me has dado

Comment: He probado la segunda opción que me diste Lucas, y el código que me devuelve python no es exactamente el mismo que obtengo con la herramienta InspeccionarElemento del navegador. Por ello que el texto y el código asociado al popup no aparece en el código que esta leyendo selenium. ¿Se te ocurre alguna otra idea? Puedo enviarte si quieres la carpeta donde tengo el .py y el geckodriver que es el que me abre el explorador

Comment: Puedes publicar el print de `page_source`. Sólo la parte donde se encuentra el pop up. intenta darle ctrl+f y busca la palabra "got it" . Edita la pregunta agregando el html donde se encuentra el boton asi puedo ayudarte. Otra consulta, usas el modo  `headless` ?. de ser asi. haz `browser.save_screenshot('asd.png')` para ver que realmente sea el modal de cookies lo que te esté molestando

Comment: @LucasDamian Lo que te quería decir antes es que haciendo el print de `page_souce` no sale ningún "Got it". En cuando a `headless` la verdad que no se que es eso, pero quizas pueda venir por ahí la solución. Por cierto, gracias por el tiempo invertido hasta ahora

Comment: Por casualidad...¿probaste de esta manera?

boton=browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[8]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/a[1]').send_keys(Keys.ESCAPE)

Agrega esto donde importas los modulos porque sino no va a dejartelo usar.
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys